# Not able to get the token in angular5

Tags: typescript, angular5

Type script code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    public token: string;
    constructor(private http: Http, private cookieService: CookieService) {}
 login(Username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.http.post('/log', JSON.stringify({ username: Username, password: password }))
            .map((response: Response) => {
                const token = response.json() && response.json().token;
```

how to get that token in my angular 
even i tried with `**const token: string = this.cookieService.get('token');**`
not able to get the token in response

Thanks in advance

Comment: That *is* how you get that token. What are you asking?!

Comment: but iam getting as undefined

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide a [mcve]. Your question says you have a token value, your comment that it's undefined; which is it? If you mean the `token` property of the service is undefined: of course it is, you never assign to it.

Comment: Edited the question can you please suggest me the solution @jonrsharpe

Comment: No, that didn't help at all. That `const` is local to your callback, it won't be accessible anywhere else. It's not clear how you thought this would work.

Answer (score 0):

convert the response to json format in that way you will get token

```
 .map((response: Response) =>{
    let res = response.json();
    let token = res.token;
```